# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: closeInfoBox is not defined (when it really is)

Tags: javascript, jquery, referenceerror

I am having an issue with my code that is causing it not to see my function even though its there.

This is my code I am using:

```
if (markerNodes.length > 0) {
     $("#locationInformation").html('<button align="center" class="btn-orange"' +
        'style="margin-right: 50px;" id="closeInfo" onclick="closeInfoBox();">' +
        'SEARCH AGAIN</button>');                
} else {
     alert('Sorry, there are no stores that close to your location.' +
             'Try expanding your search radius.');
}
```

As you can see I am dynamically adding that button to the html div id **locationInformation**.

Within that same .JS file i have that function it *say* it can not find:

```
(function ($) {
  ....[lots of code here]...

  function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     ....[lots of code here]...

     if (markerNodes.length > 0) {
          $("#locationInformation").html('<button align="center" class="btn-orange"' +
          'style="margin-right: 50px;" id="closeInfo" onclick="closeInfoBox();">' +
          'SEARCH AGAIN</button>');                
     } else {
          alert('Sorry, there are no stores that close to your location.' +
                'Try expanding your search radius.');
     }

     ....[lots of code here]...
  }

  ....[lots of code here]...

  function closeInfoBox() {
      if (hasSearched == true) {
          hasSearched = false;
          $("#addressInput").val('');
          clearLocations();
          $('.radiusDropDown').val('30');
          $('#addressInput').focus();
      }

      if (hasDirections == true) {
          slideDirections("yes");
          hasDirections = false;
      }
  }

  ....[lots of code here]...

}(jQuery));
```

So all together the .JS file looks like this (omitting code that doesn't need to be shown):

```
(function ($) {
  ....[lots of code here]...

  function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     ....[lots of code here]...

     if (markerNodes.length > 0) {
          $("#locationInformation").html('<button align="center" class="btn-orange"' +
          'style="margin-right: 50px;" id="closeInfo" onclick="closeInfoBox();">' +
          'SEARCH AGAIN</button>');                
     } else {
          alert('Sorry, there are no stores that close to your location.' +
                'Try expanding your search radius.');
     }

     ....[lots of code here]...
  }

  ....[lots of code here]...

  function closeInfoBox() {
      if (hasSearched == true) {
          hasSearched = false;
          $("#addressInput").val('');
          clearLocations();
          $('.radiusDropDown').val('30');
          $('#addressInput').focus();
      }

      if (hasDirections == true) {
          slideDirections("yes");
          hasDirections = false;
      }
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: `closeInfoBox` is not defined in global scope.  Inline event handlers can only work with globally visible variables.

Comment: You could use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead, bypassing the need for having `onclick` functions in global scope.

Comment: "align" is not a valid attribute for a `<button>` element.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is defined **inside** your `$( )` ready handler, and is therefore not visible as a global function.

There's really no good reason to be creating your element with an inline event handler:

```
      $("#locationInformation")
        .empty()
        .append($("<button/>", {
            "class": "btn-orange",
            "css": { "margin-right": "50px" }, //Needed ":"
            "id": "closeInfo",
            "click": closeInfoBox,
            "text": "SEARCH AGAIN"
        }));
```

Alternatively, instead of assigning the event handler each time you append the button, you could just set up a global delegated handler. You'd only have to do that once:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-orange", closeInfoBox);
```

That would remain in effect no matter how many times the button is added and removed.

Comment: Is there any way to reference internal functions like that? I had a project where I used a third party control that had a javascript callback. Since the callback had to be global I had to make all of my code global when I really didn't want to.

Comment: @ToniW no, there is not, unless they're explicitly exported by being assigned to a global symbol.  If they're just declared as functions and nothing is done to export them, they're local to the surrounding function and not visible from the outside.